# BackupAgent fails after package rename

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I have an app, that uses backup feature. This is line from my manifest:

```
android:backupAgent="my.package.backup.BackupAgent"
```

It works fine in current version. But now I want to move the same `BackupAgent` to another package `my.package.other.backup.package`.

When I install new version to new device, it still works fine. But when I try to install new version over old one - it causes backup agent to crash with error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.backup.BackupAgent in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

**Why Android looks for `BackupAgent` in old package?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know how to solve this problem, but finally I just create empty class on old place, that extends new one.